# How do I give access to container to have full access for a bind volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a problem deploying some docker images when I use bind volumes and when I check the logs I see errors like access denied when the docker application try to create a folder. For example the following docker compose create two containers, one for the postgres database and one for the postgres admin panel.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  PostgresDB:
    image: postgres    
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=MyDatabase
      - POSTGRES_USER=MyUser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MyPassword
    volumes: 
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  PostgresDBAdmin:  
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: MyPasword
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"

volumes:
    pgadmin:
```

For the database I use bind volume but for the panel I use normal volume. The application works fine. If I change the panel container to use bind volumes my docker compose file looks like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  PostgresDB:
    image: postgres    
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=MyDatabase
      - POSTGRES_USER=MyUser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MyPassword
    volumes: 
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  PostgresDBAdmin:  
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: MyPasword
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
       - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

This will have as a result the panel container to fail because of directory permission problem. The generated error log looks like this

```
PostgresDBAdmin_1  | ERROR  : Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions:
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |            [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin/sessions'
PostgresDBAdmin_1  | HINT   : Create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions, ensure it is writeable by
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |          'pgadmin', and try again, or, create a config_local.py file
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |          and override the SESSION_DB_PATH setting per
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |          https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.18/config_py.html
PostgresDBAdmin_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 82, in create_app_data_directory
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |     _create_directory_if_not_exists(config.SESSION_DB_PATH)
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 20, in _create_directory_if_not_exists
PostgresDBAdmin_1  |     os.mkdir(_path)
PostgresDBAdmin_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin/sessions'
```

This kind of problem is rare and I try to find a way to give access to the container to create the directory but I did not find a way to do it. The reason that I want to be able to use bind volumes is because in cases like NopCommerce it makes easier for me to have access to the files in order to create a theme.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `user:root` inside the **PostgreAdmin** Service. And the result of the docker compose file look like this :

```
PostgresDBAdmin:  
  image: dpage/pgadmin4
  user: root
  environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@example.com
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: MyPasword
    PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
  volumes:
    - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
  ports:
    - "5050:80"
```

Comment: It worked for Postgre but it did not work for other images like NopCommerce. I will mark it as accepted answer but it does not cover all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The pgadmin container process runs under a user with UID 5050.

That user needs to have access to the `./pgadmin` directory on the host.

One way to do that is to create a user on the host with that UID and make it a member of a group that has access to the `./pgadmin` directory.

If, for instance, `./pgadmin` is owned by you and your group that are both called 'pitaridis', then you can create a user called 'pgadmin' like this

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --uid 5050 --ingroup pitaridis --shell /usr/sbin/nologin pgadmin
```

Then the container process can access `./pgadmin` and create the files that it needs.

Another way that may be easier but is less secure, is to run the container as root, like this:

```
  PostgresDBAdmin:  
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: MyPasword
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
       - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    user: root
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was for a postgres container. I didn't see that it was pgadmin. I've updated my answer.